# symbolic computation program/software

Tags: math-software, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

What is your recommended symbolic computation program/software for free and commercial respectively?

What are its strength and weakness? For example, efficiency, comprehensiveness, etc

Thanks!

Comment: please advise me how to make this post wiki

Comment: Just go to edit your post and check the box "community wiki" below it.

Comment: Don't see this box. I am under firefox 3.0.19 with Ubuntu.

Comment: Try hard to look for it. Don't even have the "Answer" space. BTW is this question more suitable to ask on stackoverflow or here?

Comment: Probably because of my reputation not enough?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry, the previous comment does not apply (only applies if you want to make an answer community wiki). I am not sure how can do that after a question is posted.

Comment: @Tim: CW has been disabled for questions for regular users;just flag your question for moderator attention instead and s/he will wiki-fy for you. (I've already taken the liberty of flagging this one.)

Comment: I am just starting to look at these alternatives as well. It's completely unclear what the advantages of one package are over another, or vis-a-vis programming something oneself. It would be great to have a wiki post contrasting Sage, Maxima, Scilab, Numpy, and any other free alternatives to the (obviously excellent) Mathematica & MATLAB.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recommend [sageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), also [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) and [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/)

An easy to use is [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)

You can  to work with sage here: http://www.sagenb.org/, it is not necessary to install !!!

Comment: I have been using Mathematica lightly for years, and the reason I landed here is that Mathematica doesn't seem convenient at all to perform symbolic linear algebra (such as simplifying complicated, nested commutators involving matrices with given properties, such as unitarity, etc), at least with my current knowledge. Is Sage a better option for this?

Answer (score 5):

Both Mathematica and Maple are excellent.

It seems they have added symbolic computation toolbox for scilab (which is free). Since you are linux user, you might want to explore it. I have never personally used it though (I have used scilab itself and it does a good job of being a lilliputian Matlab)

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/scilab-scimax-doc

Comment: How about compared to matlab symbolic box, sympy in Python, Maxima?

Comment: Frankly, I haven't used the others. I especially recommend Maple, since it's really cheap for students and some universities (like mine) make a personal copy available for free.

Comment: Thanks! That is the benefit of being a student.

Comment: If you go Linux you might look at the windows emulator wine. On there homepage you can check which windows software are compatible under wine (If I am not wrong it is possible to run Maple under wine...?)

Comment: @AD: Maple does have linux compatible versions.

Answer (score 4):

Another very popular free program for symbolic computations is [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/). It is aimed somehow at computations in number theory, but its functionality is not only restricted to this. You can read a little bit about it also in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest mathHandbook.com

mathHandbook - Online symbolic math software
www.mathHandbook.com

It is an online symbolic math and computer algebra system.  It can perform exact, numeric, symbolic and graphic computation, e.g. any order of derivative, fractional calculus, solve equation, and user-defined functions, linear regression, symbolic differentation and integration, pattern-match. It is a programming language, in which you can define conditional, case, piecewise, recursive, multi-value functions and procedures, derivatives, integrals and rules. 
 It runs in any computer that supports Java. If you see it online, it can run offline in your computer. It is all of Java applet, Java application and Window application. Run MathHandbook.htm as Java applet, or run MathHandbook.bat as Java application.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Mathematica since fall 2007. I absolutely love it. It has good palettes included that help you typeset your equations more easily. It also has nice display options for giving presentations. However, if you are just wanting to typeset a paper, LaTeX is probably your best bet. TeXmaker is a very good free mac OS software for LaTeX.

Maple is another very popular computational software; however, I have not used it.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.hicalc.com is good. This is a smple http://www.hicalc.com/program/24

Hicalc is online platform to calculate expression quickly or create program with a simple, intuitive interface and share them with other people.
You can create program with almost all C# 4.0 syntax such as if, switch, while, for, foreach, etc., store and calculate your program anywhere at any time, share and Search Programs in public library.

With Hicalc, you can customize any converter and share with other people

Answer (score 0):

[DataMelt (http://jwork.org/dmelt/)](http://jwork.org/dmelt/) is free program for symbolic computation.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one mentioned the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html) which comes with MATLAB.