# Online tools for doing symbolic mathematics

Tags: online-resources, symbolic-computation

This question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11261/symbolic-computation-program-software), but specifically relates to resources available strictly as on-line web apps.  Examples include:

- [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)
- [Sage Notebook](http://www.sagenb.org)
- [hicalc](http://www.hicalc.com/)

  - not sure what this is; the site is currently blocked from my location.  I got it from the first link above.

Some basic needs:

- Ability to do symbolic manipulation on par with what you'd use Mathematica for
- Should be possible to do more than 'one-liners' (unlike Wolfram Alpha)

Comment: maple comes to mind as well

Comment: @con-f-use Maple does not have an online interface. You can all it from Sage though..

Comment: Wolfram Cloud is new and nice

Comment: sage link not working

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Added**: I found the Wikipedia article [***Comparison of Computer Algebra Systems***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems) from a link on Sage's site. Various systems are listed in tables, each identifying cost, features, etc. for each of the programs.  That may help you ultimately determine what works best for YOU!
**End "Added"**

---

I can't speak for **hicalc** (I've not heard of it!) but IMO, a good choice would be [**Sage Notebook**](http://www.sagenb.org/): it integrates a whole bunch programs: GAP, R (statistics), Pari, etc. (see more programs listed below), and you can program, as well (Python?).  I'm not sure about its graphing capabilities; though it does seem to come equipped with some graphing functionality. You can create your own account if you scroll down to the bottom of the webpage linked immediately above. (You can also peruse sample "Worksheets" from "notebooks").

Another "plus" about Sage Notebook is that you can create folders, save your work, etc, on-line, and can then thus access it (when on-line again) and pick up where you left off at another time.

**Mathematics packages contained in Sage**

Algebra: GAP, Maxima, Singular
Algebraic Geometry: Singular
Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic: MPIR, MPFR, MPFI, NTL, mpmath
Arithmetic Geometry: PARI/GP, NTL, mwrank, ecm 
Calculus:   Maxima, SymPy, GiNaC 
Combinatorics:  Symmetrica, Sage-Combinat 
Linear Algebra: ATLAS, BLAS, LAPACK, NumPy, LinBox, IML, GSL 
Graph Theory:   NetworkX 
Group Theory:   GAP 
Numerical computation:  GSL, SciPy, NumPy, ATLAS 
Number Theory:  PARI/GP, FLINT, NTL

**Other packages contained in Sage**

Command line:   IPython
Database:   ZODB, Python Pickles, SQLite
Graphical Interface:    Sage Notebook, jsmath
Graphics:   Matplotlib, Tachyon3d, GD, Jmol
Interactive programming language:   Python
Networking:     Twisted

More details available here [**Wikipedia on Sage**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAGE_%28computer_algebra_system%29).

See also [**Sage Documentation**](http://www.sagemath.org/help.html), where you can find tutorials, manuals, references, etc. available on-line and as downloads (e.g. pdf)...I've personally found the "help" mechanism in Sage quite valuable.

Comment: Besides sagenb, you can use the [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com). Over there, you not only have Sage Worksheets, but also the IPython Notebook. In both cases, you can also work with SymPy, just as you wish ;)

Comment: You might mention that a (free) login account seems to be required for the Sage options.

Answer (score 14):

[Mathics](https://mathics.github.io/) is “a free, light-weight alternative to Mathematica” built using Python and SymPy. It has an [online version](http://www.mathics.net/):

[image: Mathics web page screenshot]

Comment: link not working

Comment: @user1271772 Fixed the home page link. I took its new URL from the source code repository at https://github.com/mathics/Mathics. Wayback Machine view of older home pages: https://web.archive.org/web/20180404092800/http://www.mathics.org:80/.

Comment: Is it true that we cannot copy and paste in the Mathics online version? Also, it does not actually do any calculations, it just allows you to type in commands that look like Mathematica formatted commands?

Comment: @user1271772 The online tool does have those features. As the message at the bottom when you open the page says, press `Shift`+`Return` to submit your calculation. Pressing `Return` just creates a new line within a calculation – this mimics the interface of [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). As for copy and paste, I can copy and paste calculations and results fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 10):

Checkout http://live.sympy.org/, which is a [SymPy](http://sympy.org) session that runs on the Google App engine. It uses a persistent session system, so you can do more than just one-liners. It's actually just a Python shell, so you can do all kinds of nontrivial stuff. The only limitation is that the Google App Engine has a time limit on calculations (I think it's like 30 seconds or something).

You can also get nice LaTeX output by choosing "LaTeX" from the popup (the default is ASCII, which is more compatible, but still looks nice).

Comment: It's as though everything lately has been telling me to learn Python.  +1 for answering with precisely what I asked for: a web-based app that provides symbolic manipulation that isn't limited to one-liners.

Comment: By the way, we just updated it, so the interface is a little nicer (you no longer have to go to live.sympy.org/graphical to get nice LaTeX output, just choose "LaTeX" from the popup), and to fix some bugs.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: The online Sympy is certainly nice… when the computation is simple I prefer it to Sage, because it loads faster. The only thing that's missing is tab expansion (so you have to know the commands instead of being able to guess them).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I'll create an issue for this.  Also, you can use the Python `dir()` function to get a list of all defined names, which will include all SymPy functions.  And if you do `dir(expr)`, where x is some SymPy object, you will get a list of possible methods/properties for that object.

Comment: Ah that's useful, thanks. Should have thought of that.

Answer (score 6):

There is [QuickMath](http://www.quickmath.com) which works in it limited range if you can avoid the advertising.

Answer (score 5):

There's a magma calculator online [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), but your programs are limited to 60 seconds which should be sufficient for most things.

Answer (score 3):

This one is good too:

https://www.mathway.com/problemwidget.aspx

(blah blah, 30 char limit, blah blah)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for symbolic calculations using Octave / Matlab,
 [SCaVis is a good choice](http://jwork.org/scavis/). You can learn build-in jMatLab program.

There is also a tutorial on [jLearn page](http://jwork.org/learn).

Answer (score 2):

As this question is old, (today 11/29/2106), a lot of the links in the answers are now broken. Here is an up to date list.

- [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/)
- [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)
- [SymPy Live](http://live.sympy.org/)
- [Cymath](https://www.cymath.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are various online [code](http://codepad.org/) [compilers](http://ideone.com/) you could use for this purpose, assuming you know an appropriate language. Both the linked services support Haskell, a particular favorite of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this online Computer Algebra Calculator:

http://www.omega-math.com

It only requires free registraton. There is also a quick reference at

http://www.omega-math.com/nhome/qr.jsp