# Is downloading a Symbolic Computation software still justifiable?

Tags: soft-question, math-software, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

First: I'm not 100% sure if this is the place to be asking this, but I figured this would seem out-of-place in stack overflow.

Second, some background: I recently asked a question here about integrating some expression. I had tried both Maxima and Sympy (the only two Computer Algebra Systems I use) and they both failed.

Then one of the comments pointed out that Wolfram Alpha solved it! Which made me feel a bit stupid because basically I had overlooked the obvious easiest approach, which was to "google it" (almost). This is because in my understanding CASs should be able to do more than Wolfram Alpha, which I thought was aimed to be something more accessible to everybody rather than a really complete and specialized system.

Furthermore, in some other times both Maxima and Sympy have also let me down, but I won't get into that for now.

Obviously CASs can do things Wolfram Alpha can't. Like when we need many lines and to actually do algebra, etc. WA is more for one-liners.

But, if we don't consider problems that involve more than one line of code, is there a still a reason, in this day and age, to seek CASs instead of just using tools off the internet? (Considering that being free is almost a must-have.)

I ask this also because the problem might be that I'm also just not using the right CAS.

PS.: This is related to [this old question from 2010](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11261/symbolic-computation-program-software). I figure things have changed a lot from then to now.

Comment: "CASs instead of just using tools off the internet" The two are not mutually exclusive: https://tio.run/#maxima